# Four-words (----||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

**Four-words:**
My first is indivisible, but not really.
My second is a cloak worn by men, but in ancient Rome.
My third is a cruel wicked person, but not a human.
My fourth is about 20 quires, but in reverse.

I was not allowed a very short title for this puzzle, but I was able to **add a clue to make it cross the 15-letters-minimum limit for titles**.

Comment: Jigsaw puzzle tag? Hmm...

Comment: Great puzzle! That tag together with the title told me what sort of puzzle it was, and having found 2 and 4, I then quickly got 1 and 3.

Comment: @randal'thor , thanks !! Maybe I have to make it a little tougher for quick solvers like you eg by removing the jigsaw tag !!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

*My first is indivisible, but not really.*

> The word ATOM means "indivisible" in ancient Greek, but atoms aren't really indivisible since they have protons, neutrons, quarks, etc. inside them.

*My second is a cloak worn by men, but in ancient Rome.*

> A TOGA

[is the answer there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toga).

*My third is a cruel wicked person, but not a human.*

> An OGRE.

*My fourth is about 20 quires, but in reverse.*

[20 quires](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Units_of_paper_quantity#Quire)

> form a ream, so the answer to this is MAER.

And the full answer is:

> `A T O M`
> `T O G A`
> `O G R E`
> `M A E R`

*Lovely* puzzle!

Comment: +1 , & thanks for the DOUBLE compliment ("Lovely puzzle!" & making a new puzzle inspired by this)

Answer (score 2):

Specifically Expected Answer:

> The clue **---- ||||** refers to a **4x4 grid** where there are 4 words (4 letters each) **horizontally**, and the same grid gives the same words **vertically**.
>  This **restriction** fixes the possible values for each of the clues, which may have many matches in isolation.
>  1st word, Protons may be considered "indivisible, but not really" because they are made of quarks, but we can not split the Proton into 3 quarks. ATOM by Definition or Etymology, mean Indivisible, but we have been able to split that into Electrons, Protons and Neutrons.
>  2nd word, there may have been a wide variety of cloaks worn in Rome, but TOGA starts with T (2nd letter of ATOM)
>  3rd word, there may be many Different Possibilities, but not many start with O (3rd letter of ATOM). Anyway let us skip it for now.
>  4th word, 20 quires make a ream, but that will not start with M (last letter of ATOM). So the clue says "in reverse" so make that MAER, which starts with M.
>  Now it is a simple matter to fill in OGRE.

---

> **ATOM**
>  **TOGA**
>  **OGRE**
>  **MAER**

---

I seem to have initiated a **MEME** with this simple puzzle : "rand al'thor" was inspired to make a 5-word variant, then "Engineer Toast" made variants for sizes 6 & 7 & 8 , finally "Avon" made 6-word variants twice.

Comment: Actually I thought ATOM was one of the harder clues to get. MAER was easy since unambiguous, and then TOGA was also easy (you say "there may have been a wide variety of cloaks worn in Rome", but Google only seems to know of one!)

Comment: @randal'thor , When I woke up, I replied to your comment, but now I do not see that reply. Wondering if I imagined commenting (still half-asleep) ? Something strange ? (FYI : I referred to pallium & abolla in that comment )

Comment: Mods can delete other people's comments, but I can't see why they'd do that here. Maybe you clicked the 'delete comment' button by accident??

Comment: @randal'thor , I think the "MODS DONE IT" , because deleting comments shows this "Really delete this comment?" which I would have seen that, even half-asleep. It would be good, if there were notifications like "Comment Deleted"

Comment: Weird. Why would they have deleted your comment? I assume you didn't say anything inappropriate? I've seen them delete whole chains of comments before, but usually only when there was an argument or personal discussion or a mention of something they didn't like. Maybe we should take it to meta?

Comment: I copy-pasted two lines from [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pallium_%28Roman_cloak%29 ] &  [ http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abolla ] , which might break "copyright" laws ? If it happens again, I will see if META helps