# Five-words (-----|||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

**Five-words:**

My first is a kind of cattle from Asia (more than one).
My second is what a horse did to its victory if it just won a race on its own merit.
My third is found together with a groom.
My fourth is the kind of praise a jockey gets if they just won a race by cheating.
My fifth is a horse, or any animal that can be ridden.

(Inspired by Prem's [Four-words (----||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words).)

Comment: +1 , thanks for mentioning my puzzle here. Now somebody may come up with Six-words (------||||||)

Comment: @Prem And Seven-words, and Eight-words, and Six-words again!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Cool puzzle!

The answers to the clues are:

> 1) **Zebus** (an Asian cow thing) 
>  2) The horse **earnt** its victory 
>  3) **Bride**, of course 
>  4) He cheated, so his praise is **undue** 
>  5) An animal that can be ridden is generally called a **steed**

Arranged:

> `Z E B U S`
> `E A R N T`
> `B R I D E`
> `U N D U E`
> `S T E E D`

Comment: +1, well, well, well, this is the first time that between the time I added a puzzle and the time I woke up after a short nap, (A) the puzzle was answered, and (B) it inspired a new puzzle based on that format and (C) even that new puzzle was solved and (D) both puzzles have good upvotes.

Comment: @Prem that's because these puzzles are fun :D also I couldn't figure out zebus xD

Comment: @Wouter , yes , we are all here for having fun !! & entertaining other folks !! Hope you had better success with the 4 word puzzle ? (20% easier ?)

Comment: @Prem And Four, Five, _and_ Six words were all on HNQs last time I checked! I've had enough UVs today mainly out of these 2 puzzles to put me at double the repcap :-o

Comment: I will definitely accept your answer, but please could you add in explanations for posterity as to how each line of the OP gives the word you say?