# Six-words (------) Six-words (||||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

**Six-words:**

> My first is what a bouncer does if they think you're cool enough
>   My second is what my fourth does to your pain
>   My third is your surroundings on a grassy hill in summer
>   My fourth is taken to do my second to your pain
>   My fifth lives in places they do not own
>   My sixth is what you do with prize-winning animals
>   
>   My first gathers liquid on to a surface
>   My second is where Leo kept going in Inception
>   My third is a branch of the US Military
>   My fourth is what you must do to solve this puzzle
>   My fifth is something shaped like a camper's home
>   My sixth is what well-off rude people may do to the less fortunate

---

Inspired by [Five-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15341/9000) and [Four-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15339/9000) but this puzzle is a little different as there are two things being described. They're very tightly related but they're not twins.

Comment: There's a branch of the US Military that's six letters long? O_o

Comment: @BaileyM Marine?

Comment: @BaileyM It may not be the official "headings for formal documents" name but certainly fits in the sentence "My brother just joined the _ _ _ _ _ _."

Comment: We have to solve two squares, then find a relationship?

Comment: @leoll2 I didn't say it was two *squares* being described, just two things. No, you don't have to solve two squares.

Comment: @EngineerToast the first one is horizontal, the second one vertical, correct?

Comment: I think this should be "12-words", not "6-words". Another possibility is "6-words (------) + 6-words (||||||)"

Comment: I think you just changed the wrong line to your puzzle! A bouncer certainly admits people if he thinks they're cool enough.

Comment: @BaileyM See? There goes the internet a**b**sorbing my attention and inducing me to change the wrong line. Thanks.

Comment: Did you take this from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Word_square#Double_word_squares)?

Comment: @noedne I can't remember but I almost definitely did. I'm not clever enough to generate that on my own in any reasonable time frame.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> `ADMITS` 
>   `DEADEN` 
>   `SERENE` 
>   `OPIATE` 
>   `RENTER` 
>   `BREEDS`

What a fun little puzzle.

Comment: You got it *despite* my confusion between absorb and adsorb. I've fixed it now but good job succeeding over my inadequacies!

Comment: Thank you for the formatting, I wasn't quite sure how to do that. And I would hardly call it an inadequacy- these must be hard to make!