# Seven-words (-------|||||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

**Seven-words:**

> My first is what the bully may show
>   My second describes some spouses post-nuptials
>   My third is when something is like something else
>   My fourth are people who tell you what to pay
>   My fifth are microscopic and may move through you
>   My sixth will reduce your quality
>   My seventh is something that Homer wrote

---

In the neo-tradition of [Four-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15339/9000), [Five-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15341/9000), and [Six-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15347/9000).

Comment: Can't wait for 42-words

Comment: @leoll2 I expect that shortly we will start reversing the order of the puzzle sizes. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> ```
> BRAVADO 
> RENAMED 
> ANALOGY 
> VALUERS 
> AMOEBAS 
> DEGRADE 
> ODYSSEY
> ```

Comment: I suspect you've figured me out...