# Eight-words (--------||||||||) +1

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

**Eight-words:** (+1)

> My first is a move in (American) football that will never score you points
>   My second is like the shaft within a flagellum
>   My third is really two words and surrounds the feline's path
>   My fourth is you sitting, ready to travel afar
>   My fifth you just got home from travelling by different means
>   My sixth is food served with the nut of a tree
>   My seventh is a boat with a sail at two score five degrees
>   My eighth are the children on a snowy weekend

---

In the neo-tradition of [Four-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15339/9000), [Five-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15341/9000), [Six-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15347/9000), and [Seven-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/q/15354/9000).

---

I suspect leoll2 may have figured me out...

Comment: Yes, I figured it out eheh!

Comment: Why the +1 in the title?

Comment: @BaileyM Because "toe plate" is two words.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> ```
> LATERALS
> AXONEMAL
> TOEPLATE 
> ENPLANED
> RELANDED
> AMANDINE
> LATENEER
> SLEDDERS
> ```

Comment: Well, I won't worry about Nine-Words, then.

Comment: Just wondering if other exist...

Comment: There are word squares of the order 1 and 2 (although they're trivial) and up to 9. There are examples of 10 word squares but they're not "perfect".