# Another Four-words (----||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

It's been a while since we have seen one of these (as originally created by [Prem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10940/prem)), and I thought people might enjoy another one. (See [the original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words) for the solution format.)

My first is the conclusion of all.
My second is the beginning of all.
My third is the requirement of all.
My fourth is the ceasing of all.

Comment: Any letterplay in this one?

Comment: @randal'thor Not on this one.

Comment: this looks hard

Comment: 'all' is each sentence is referring to the same group, or this is not necessary the case?

Comment: @Alex Yes, but that isn't necessarily required to find the answer.

Comment: We should have a [tag:gnomic] tag for puzzles like this.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here is my answer:

> D O N E
>  O P E N
>  N E E D
>  E N D S

Explanation:

> "Done" is a way to describe conclusion (ending) of an activity or experience.
>  "Open" describes a beginning, as in "the *open*ing number of a show".
>  "Need" describes a requirement: "You *need* good grades to get into MIT."
>  "Ends" is a bit of a stretch, because it's plural, but a "ceasing" is an *end*.

Comment: Very well done. Stupid needing a plural, so I'll pretend that I meant the "end of all" means the "ends" as all could imply multiple items :-D

Comment: What a relief to finally see the answer.  +1