# Cryptic Five-words (-----|||||)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

Inspired by [Aggie Kidd](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/9951/aggie-kidd)'s [redux](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/another-four-words/) of the original "[Four-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words)" puzzle by [Prem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10940/prem), I decided to create a similar "Five-words" puzzle.

Some clues are intentionally somewhat vague and/or misleading, to keep it from being *too* easy, but they should all make sense when the solution is determined.

> My first's what ant calls a cricket, no doubt
>   My second is third when you really zoom out
>   My third will protect you from villain or foe
>   My fourth won't get verdant when it's on the go
>   My fifth's what you did with the game that you lost
>   My whole is a square with five words that are crossed

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Here is my answer:

> ```
> B E A S T
> E A R T H
> A R M O R
> S T O N E
> T H R E W
> ```

Explanation:
My first's what ant calls a cricket, no doubt

> A cricket would be a **beast** to an ant.

My second is third when you really zoom out

> The **earth** is the third planet if we zoom out on the solar system.

My third will protect you from villain or foe

> **Armor** protects you from everyone.

My fourth won't get verdant when it's on the go

> Verdant is green, moss is green, rolling **stone** gathers no moss.

My fifth's what you did with the game that you lost

> You **threw** the game.

Comment: Looks like you got it! +1

Comment: Excellent!  I was actually thinking of FEAST for the first one, but your answer is just as good.

Comment: Good job! Nice to know I had a good idea with a few of them, Stone was the one that I really wanted to use.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, can you explain FEAST?  I don't get it.

Comment: @dennisdeems If ants killed a cricket, it would be quite the feast for them.

Comment: Seems like there could be a better clue; the rest are wonderful.

Comment: Yes, @AggieKidd got what I was thinking.  It did seem a little weak, but every other clue I could think of for "feast" seemed too obvious.  I never thought of using "beast" (or "yeast" or "least", etc.)

Answer (score 2):

Closest I can figure out is

```
G I A N T
I _ R _ H
A R M O R
N _ O _ E
T H R E W
```

But I am lost on 4, which should be a synonym for stone.
Got no clue for 2.

Comment: I put your answer into a fixed-width font for readability - hope you don't mind!

Comment: It might help to know that there probably aren't any words of the format I_R_H. [Litscape](http://www.litscape.com/word_tools/pattern_match.php) is a useful tool. The fourth word could only be NOOSE.

Comment: I had to start with stone and work my way back.

Comment: Without seeing your answer, I got the same - except I didn't even get stone :p

Answer (score 0):

Partial answer:

*My first's what ant calls a cricket, no doubt*

> JUMPY (compared to an ant, a cricket does a lot of jumping).

*My second is third when you really zoom out*
*My third will protect you from villain or foe*
*My fourth won't get verdant when it's on the go*

> Not sure about these yet.

*My fifth's what you did with the game that you lost*

> YIELD (when you lose a game, you yield).

Comment: I also considered HOPPY for #1...