# Another cryptic Five-word (with a twist)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

My [last Five-words puzzle](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16945/cryptic-five-words) seemed well-received, so I thought I'd try another.  This one has a bit of a twist to it, which shouldn't be too hard to figure out.

I expect it will be easier to solve overall than the previous one.

> My first can be pleasant, or horribly foul
>   My second is useful to hunt waterfowl
>   My third is an act that can cause desolation
>   My fourth might be done to a sleepy dalmatian
>   My fifth talks of galleons -- many, not one
>   With just these five clues, you are only half done.
>
> My first keeps you warm when a cold wind is blowing
>   My second is music to sing when it's snowing
>   My third is an action describing what follows
>   My fourth could be used to catch rabbits or swallows
>   My fifth is a truth that you hold very dear
>   With all these ten clues, the result should be clear

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm going to go with:

> ```
> S C E N T
> C A N O E
> A R S O N
> R O U S E
> F L E E T
> ```

My first can be pleasant, or horribly foul

> A **scent** can either be very nice, or pretty awful (for instance, compare roses and skunks).

My second is useful to hunt waterfowl

> Some people hunt ducks and other waterfowl from a **canoe**.

My third is an act that can cause desolation

> You can cause desolation by burning the place down, which is an act of **arson**.

My fourth might be done to a sleepy dalmatian

> You **rouse** something to wake it up, which you could do to anything sleepy, including a dalmatian!

My fifth talks of galleons -- many, not one

> A galleon is a sailing ship, which in multiples creates a **fleet**.

My first keeps you warm when a cold wind is blowing

> A **scarf** worn around your neck protects you from the cold wind.

My second is music to sing when it's snowing

> This is a pretty direct reference to a Christmas **carol**.

My third is an action describing what follows

> What is about to **ensue** is what will follow.

My fourth could be used to catch rabbits or swallows

> You can catch rabbits or swallows with a rope trap, or a **noose**.

My fifth is a truth that you hold very dear

> A **tenet** is a truth or belief, specifically a religious one, which you certainly do hold dear.

Comment: That was fast :O

Comment: Wow!  Very fast!  Congratulations.  I guess twice the number of clues makes it a lot easier to solve.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain, I love these puzzles :) I was able to latch on to the words 'scarf', 'carol', and 'fleet' very early, and from there I filled in the blanks.