# Some four word puzzles (and possible bounty)

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

A four word puzzle (see [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/another-four-words)) is basically a 4x4 grid containing 4 4-letter words, and reads the same top to bottom or left to right. For example,

```
A B C D
B E F G
C F H I
D G I J
```

Here are some puzzles with hints (not necessarily in the same order):

**Sample puzzle**

a shape
an identity
a valley
an audio track

**Answer**

```
S O N G
O V A L
N A M E
G L E N
```

**Puzzle 1**

a flower
a plant
a stage in life
a fraction of a whole

**Puzzle 2**

a medium of writing
an examination
a mark joining two points
a narrow cut

**Puzzle 3**

a kind of footwear
a kind of sensation
obedience
squashing things together

**Puzzle 4**

stack
volume
termination
a metal

**Possible bounty**

I know it's quite unlikely, but if a single person manages to be the first one to solve 3 of the 4 puzzles, you will get a bounty of 100 rep (plus up-votes from many people).

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Puzzle 1**

> `PART` - a fraction of a whole
> `ALOE` - a plant
> `ROSE` - a flower
> `TEEN` - a stage in life

**Puzzle 3**

> `MASH` - squashing things together
> `ACHE` - a kind of sensation
> `SHOE` - a kind of footwear
> `HEED` - obedience

**Puzzle 4**

> `PILE` - stack
> `IRON` - a metal
> `LOUD` - volume
> `ENDS` - termination

Answer (score 8):

Puzzle 2:

> `S L I T`
>      `L I N E`
>      `I N K S`
>      `T E S T`