# A few Four Word Puzzles, and a Five Word Challenge

Tags: word, wordplay, crosswords, word-square

After (rather quickly) solving the puzzles found in [this link,](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/17907/some-four-word-puzzles-and-possible-bounty) I decided to make a few of my own (along with my little sister helping make one).

The following is a quote how [ghosts_in_the_code](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/4269/ghosts-in-the-code) explained these puzzles (because he/she/ghost did very well in describing it).

> A four word puzzle (see [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words) and [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/16887/another-four-words)) is basically a 4x4
>   grid containing 4 4-letter words, and reads the same top to bottom or
>   left to right. For example,
>
> ```
> A B C D
> B E F G
> C F H I
> D G I J
> ```
>
> Here are some puzzles with hints (not necessarily in the same order):
>
> **Sample puzzle**
>
> a shape
>   an identity
>   a valley
>   an audio track
>
> **Answer**
>
> ```
> S O N G
> O V A L
> N A M E
> G L E N
> ```

**Puzzle 1**

Type of coffee or tea
Significant role
Whirlpool
Document

**Puzzle 2**

Mother Earth
Simple
Man-eating monster
Manipulates an outcome

**Puzzle 3**

Children summer activity
Work the fields
Figure skating move
Short note

**Puzzle 4 5x5**

Macho
Italian food
Ski resort
Metal alloy
Twitch

Good luck and have fun!

Comment: What's the reason for posting these all as a single question?  Wouldn't it make more sense to post each one as a separate question, since they are all distinct puzzles, and aren't directly related to each other (aside from the format)?

Comment: I prefer to get more than 1 of these in a question because they are so simple to solve.  Thus from the asker's role I did exactly that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Puzzle 1**

> Type of coffee or tea:  **ICED**
>  Significant role:  **LEAD**
>  Whirlpool:  **EDDY**
>  Document:  **FILE**
>
>  `F I L E`
>  `I C E D`
>  `L E A D`
>  `E D D Y`

**Puzzle 2**

> Mother Earth:  **GAIA**
>  Simple:  **EASY**
>  Man-eating monster:  **OGRE**
>  Manipulates an outcome:  **RIGS**
>
>  `O G R E`
>  `G A I A`
>  `R I G S`
>  `E A S Y`

**Puzzle 3**

> Children's summer activity:  **CAMP**
>  Work the fields:  **PLOW**
>  Figure skating move:  **AXEL**
>  Short note:  **MEMO**
>
>  `C A M P`
>  `A X E L`
>  `M E M O`
>  `P L O W`

**Puzzle 4**

> Macho:  **MANLY**
>  Italian food:  **PASTA**
>  Ski resort:  **ASPEN**
>  Metal alloy:  **STEEL**
>  Twitch:  **SPASM**
>
>  `S P A S M`
>  `P A S T A`
>  `A S P E N`
>  `S T E E L`
>  `M A N L Y`

Comment: Sorry to the others; I was composing this answer on my phone, which took a while. I didn't see the other answers until I posted this. (I did solve them all myself.)

Answer (score 4):

Puzzle 4:

> `S P A S M`
>      `P A S T A`
>      `A S P E N`
>      `S T E E L`
>      `M A N L Y`

Answer (score 4):

Puzzle 2:

> `O G R E`
>      `G A I A`
>      `R I G S`
>      `E A S Y`

Puzzle 3:

> `C A M P`
>      `A X E L`
>      `M E M O`
>      `P L O W`