# Five-words (-----|||||) brought back

Tags: word, word-square

Again, it's been a while since we have seen one of these, so I thought I should throw another one out there. (See [the original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words) for the solution format.)

My first has been seen around here a lot recently. (September 2015)
My second is what my first does this weekend.
My third provides a welcome breeze.
My fourth begins a clue, but is only within.
My fifth presented why I am right.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's:

> `M O V I E`
> `O P E N S`
> `V E N T S`
> `I N T R A`
> `E S S A Y`

My first has been seen around here a lot recently. (September 2015)

> The [**MOVIE** tag](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-movies?cb=1) has been used a lot, recently.

My second is what my first does this weekend.

> Movies open (are released) on weekends --> a movie **OPENS**

My third provides a welcome breeze.

> **VENTS** carry air through structures.

My fourth begins a clue, but is only within.

> An INTRO begins something, **INTRA** is a prefix meaning "within"

My fifth presented why I am right.

> An **ESSAY** can make an argument.

Comment: Well done. Check the fourth clue though. Your answer is right, but you talk about an *Intro* rather than *Intra*

Comment: haha, yeah. I was typing too fast, but fixed it already. Will this explanation suffice?

Comment: Perfectly done.

Comment: A puzzle which references the ongoing Topic Challenge, I wonder if this could be considered for a meta-[on-topic](http://meta.puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/4351/fortnightly-topic-challenge-1-movies?cb=1) list.