# Spooky Five Words (-----|||||)

Tags: word, word-square, seasonal

Bringing this puzzle type back again.
(See [the original](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words) for the solution format.)

My first is what you will seek.
My second is what you should be.
My third is something all monsters have.
My fourth is what you may feel.
My fifth is the shameful answer the following day.

Hint

> For 5, there is an abbreviation involved.

Comment: I would like to know the shameful answer the following day, to which question =)

Comment: @Alex The question is obviously, "Did you eat *all* your Halloween candy in one night?"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And the *spooky* solution is...

> $$\begin{matrix}C&A&N&D&Y\\A&W&A&R&E\\N&A&M&E&S\\D&R&E&A&D\\Y&E&S&D&A\\\end{matrix}$$

Comment: Masterfully done. I'll accept the answer tomorrow.

Comment: Nooooo it's been answered!  Ha good job