# Yet another Four-words (----||||)

Tags: word, crosswords, word-square

Just had an idea on a new Four words question:

(See the original for the solution format
[Four-words (----||||)](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339/four-words)):

1) I am a visual definition of myself when you had the answer
2) My position is kind of contradicting with what I am
3) This one is easy once you figure out the rest
4) I am the same as 1)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> `E D G E`
> `D E A D`
> `G A N G`
> `E D G E`

Because the second one is not in the exact center ;)

Comment: you got it, nicely done!