# A Rhyming Six-Words Puzzle

Tags: word, wordplay, rhyme, word-square

*In the spirit of the original [Four-words](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/15339) puzzle by [Prem](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/10940), and all those that followed.*

> My first completely overshadows anything you see.
>   My second's used extensively to mean extensively.
>   My third are pithy aphorisms commonly dispersed.
>   My fourth's what you'll be feeling if Deusovi solves this first.
>   My fifth's predominantly white, though legend says it's golden.
>   My sixth is what will keep the world consistently unfolding.
>
> My whole's a square that's six by six with letters in each cell.
>   There is no difference in the words read flat or vertical.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

> `D W A R F S`
>  `W I D E L Y`
>  `A D A G E S`
>  `R E G R E T`
>  `F L E E C E`
>  `S Y S T E M`

**EDIT:** M***oooooo*ooooo**m, do I *have* to explain every line? FINE.

`My first completely overshadows anything you see.`

> aye, something that *dwarfs* everything could be said to *overshadow* it

`My second's used extensively to mean extensively.`

> *widely*, even. Judge I object to having to explain this one, res ipsa loquitur

`My third are pithy aphorisms commonly dispersed.`

> *adages* is another word for aphorisms

`My fourth's what you'll be feeling if Deusovi solves this first.`

> well, yes, I *would* be *regret*ful if the god of false-egg-plurals had beaten me to it, but they did not

`My fifth's predominantly white, though legend says it's golden.`

> *fleece* is white, but there's that whole [Jason thing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_Fleece)

`My sixth is what will keep the world consistently unfolding.`

> *systems* are the logic by which things can be said to run

Comment: Well, that didn't take long...

Comment: I was hoping @Deusovi didn't solve this first, since it might invalidate the clue for #4...    :P

Comment: I'm curious which one you got first; I thought a couple might be too easy.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain 5 came to me really quickly, then either 3 or 2, and the rest unfolded from there.

Comment: @GentlePurpleRain: I take *one* nap and this happens... *grumble*